# if isset doesn't work in php

Tags: forms, post, isset

I'm having a form with only one submit button. I don't know why, but when I use this code and I click on the submit button, nothing is happening. If I use a ! before the isset you'll see the echo in the page. I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" name="addImg" />
</form>
<?
    if (isset($_POST['addImg'])) {echo "haaallloooo";}
?>
```

Comment: Set your form method to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, form by default is sending variables by get, try using method="POST" attribute in form tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the method to POST.

Otherwise you can use:

`$_REQUEST['addImg']`

The variable `$_REQUEST` can access both `GET` and `POST` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Form needs an action and a method.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" name="addImg" />
</form>
<?
    if (isset($_POST['addImg'])) {echo "haaallloooo";}
?>
```

Regarding "isset", if $_POST['addImg'] is not set, it doesn't echo "haaallloooo".

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Check http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php